# Creating dynamic manifest files that work with ipads and iphones

Tags: iphone, asp.net, ipad, html, manifest

**Problem:** The browsers within apples ipad and iphone don't seem to like dynamically generated manifest files (we constantly get errors involving either missing images or .aspx pages that can be accessed from the device or "Application Cache manifest could not be fetched"). We originally had a manifest.ashx acting as our manifest that would dynamically create and pull some pieces from the web server for offline app functionality. This process worked fine for the majority of browsers and mobile devices but failed on the apple products.

**Thoughts:** For some reason safari doesn't seem to register the manifest.ashx correctly (this is where we dynamically create the manifest file) and just gives up on trying to open it. We truly need a dynamic manifest file for the requirements of the project so switching to a static manifest file would not work. Does anyone have any suggestions towards alternative creation methods for dynamic manifest files?

**Code:**
manifest.ashx

```
public class Manifest : IHttpHandler
{

 public void ProcessRequest( HttpContext context )
 {
   ManifestGenerator generator = new ManifestGenerator();

   context.Response.ContentType = "text/cache-manifest";
   //Create the dynamic manifest file here (returns the manifest as a string)
   context.Response.Write( generator.GenerateManifest() );
   context.Response.Flush();
 }
}
```

Thanks,

**Updated Thoughts v1:** Leaning towards thinking this maybe a device specific manifest fault as all the other mobile and desktop devices are accessing the app just fine (including being able to go offline). Currently I have moved back to a dynamically generated manifest (within the manifest.ashx) and the ipad / iphone still dies when trying to fetch but it does get further then it did before (error was: *"Application Cache update failed, because "file path goes here" could not be fetched"*). A strange aside to this is the fact that the desktop version of safari handles the web app just fine (as well as an install of chrome on the ipad had no troubles accessing the site on/off line) while the mobile versions of it do not.

**Updated Thoughts v2:** Seems that this issue is safari specific as I have the web app running online/offline with chrome for the apple products (iphone/ipad). Still looking for a fix / work around for the safari browsers though...

Comment: Currently the "Live Document" on the W3 site clearly states the extension of this file is to be .webmanifest (https://w3c.github.io/manifest/#media-type-registration). This isn't an "Apple" problem but browsers not conforming to the standards problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Safari/iPad, the manifest file must end with .manifest.  Atleast, that's what my tests determined.

So, in order to make this work, you will have to dynamically generate the .manifest file using a HttpHandler and some changes in web.config to do map cache.maifest to the handler.  The idea is that the call to the non-existent cache.manifest would actually get mapped to the handler, which would then send back dynamic content.

This is currently the part I'm stuck at, so I cannot help you here yet.